# Whole-System Snapshot on windows server 2008 R2

Tags: sharepoint-2010, replication, windows-server-2008-r2, snapshot, system-restore

I am working with a server farm with sharepoint 2010, MS SQL Server 2008 and other required softwares installed in it. Is there any tool available with the help of that I can take the snapshot of the whole running system for replication onto another server farm?